# appreciate how to find regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Please help me to get the price of a string variable. It is desirable to use regular expressions.

```
import re

qw = 'US $1 719,57'
search = re.search('.*?([\d| |,]*)', qw)
qw = search.group(1)
if qw:
    print(qw)
```

As a result should be able to:

> 1 719.57

ie: let numbers and symbols "," ","

Comment: How about simply, `([\d., ]+)$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to just `qw.replace('US $'` which yields what you want. Static string replacement is almost always faster than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use something like this:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d{2})?\b
```

This will match a number of the format you specified, with space as thousand separators and comma for decimals (optional).

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dO7tW1)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you really mean there will be space after the 1 in your input.

```
qw = 'US $1 719,57'
qw = re.sub("[^\d,]", "", qw)    
qw = re.sub(",", ".", qw)
print qw
```

Output will be `1719.57` instead of `1 719.57`